# refund customer's money through magento site [credit memo ]

Tags: payment, creditmemo, store-credit

after customer's order is cancelled. site owner have to refund the money to customer.

is there any method in magento admin panel or through any extension , site owner

can refund the money to customer through online in magento site.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. From the invoice you want to Refund, click the Credit Memo button.
2. Specify the Qty to Refund and then click the Update Qty's button.
3. Create credit memo
4. You should then see the refund button.
   [image]

Comment: This is of course highly dependent on the payment extension used, and that it implements on-line refunds. If it does not, the refund will only be off-line, and you'd need to refund via the payment gateway interface

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I want to give an option for customers that if order is cancelled, than saving their money in credit points so that they can use that amount to buy for other products....

Comment: In that case you will need an extension that adds that functionality. Something like http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-credit-pro-extension-by-mageworld.html

Comment: @user9434334345 - your comment does not (at all) match the question. please update the question accordingly.

Comment: @ProxiBlue no, actually i want to refund through online only , but as there is no option through online

to pay back , we have to use atleast credit points.... so i went with that comment....

Comment: Anyone help me how can i give amount return to customer magento account, not refund via Bank account.